# Open an Ontology with KAON2 Reasoner

Tags: java, ontology

I have a KAON2 Reasoner and I want to open an Ontology with that.
How  is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `Example01.java` included in the distribution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OntologyManager ontologyManager=KAON2Manager.newOntologyManager();
    DefaultOntologyResolver resolver=new DefaultOntologyResolver();
    resolver.registerReplacement("http://kaon2.semanticweb.org/example01","file:src/ex01/example01.xml");
    ontologyManager.setOntologyResolver(resolver);
    Ontology ontology=ontologyManager.openOntology("http://kaon2.semanticweb.org/example01",new HashMap<String,Object>());
    ...
}
```

Where the first and the last line are the important part; lines 2-4 just tell the `ontologyManager` to load from a local file.

**Edit:** as described [here](http://www.neon-toolkit.org/pipermail/plugin-developers/2009-July/000256.html), it does not work with newer java versions. I tested it with JDK 1.6.12, which worked.

Comment: I have set the path to the porvided XML file in the example but I received the foloowing error
ayda maleki  ( 10 Jun 8:24 ) :‎  Exception in thread "main" org.semanticweb.kaon2.api.KAON2Exception: Error in parsing.
at org.semanticweb.kaon2.pdb.a(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.kaon2.hs.parseOntology(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.kaon2.gr.a(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.kaon2.er.b(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.kaon2.er.a(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.kaon2.be.b(Unknown Source)

Comment: at org.semanticweb.kaon2.be.f(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.kaon2.ud.openOntology(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.kaon2.ud.openOntology(Unknown Source)
at ThesisTest.main(ThesisTest.java:49)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException
at org.semanticweb.kaon2.mv.a(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.kaon2.pdb.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXP